# Cannot access internet at all

Tags: internet, connection

I am new to ubuntu and have a wired connection.. it is working on windows 10 but somehow it's not working on linux..I don't have wifi..I'm only using one cable. [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j88j.png)
[My connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smU9J.png) 
Version: 18.04.3 LTS 64bit

Output of lspci -knn : https://pastebin.com/cve19ndE

Output of lspci:https://pastebin.com/pGwsDp0w

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`.

Comment: What is the make and model of the Network Interface Card you have? It would help to list that. Try `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'` and consider pasting the output above.

Comment: Are you using some any external Ethernet dongle?

Comment: grep Eth-A3 does nothing here... I'm doing this edits on the phone, it's quite hard..

Comment: @TalesAmaral the command was `grep Eth -A3` with a space before the hyphen.

Comment: I tried with the space.. grep Eth - A3 @MukeshSaiKumar

Comment: There is no PCI Ethernet device.

Comment: What is the make and model of the box you are using? Are you using the built in Network Interface Card that came with that box, or, like @Pilot6 asked, are you using some sort of external Ethernet dongle hooked in via, say, USB. Also, if you have access to a newer version of Ubuntu, like Bionic, and are not attached to 18.04.3 you may want to consider upgrading and see if the problem goes away. Nonetheless it will be super useful to have the info on what hardware you have and potentially report your problem to Canonical as a bug if it is one.

Comment: @DavidWest I'm using the built in interface card, and I can't upgrade it right now

Comment: Even if a PCI device is not supported buy the kernel, it would be shown in `lspci` anyway.

Comment: That must be some other interface. Can you boot into Windows and show what is shown in its Device Manager regarding Ethernet?

Comment: @Pilot6i can't boot in, But when i was using Windows it was working..

Comment: also egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet' does nothing @DavidWest

Comment: @Tales Amaral. What company makes your laptop, PC, or whatever you are using? More hardware details, please, including a specific model number for the machine. Since it is the built in hardware we can look up the exact model of the NIC you are using if we have that info.

Comment: @DavidWest it's a PC. I don't know the NIC, but i know the motherboard... it's a N68-GS4 FX, ASrock...

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your last comment I looked up the specs and you are likely using a Qualcomm Atheros AR8171.

After Googling it looks like you want the `alx` module loaded during boot.

Try this:
`echo 'alx' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules && sudo reboot`

Note: I originally thought you wanted `alc` but I tested it and I could not get that to load in stock 18.04.3 off a fresh install.

`alx` does load, and per [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/alx) it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux OS's allow you to run a live OS from a media device such as a USB. Please note that whilst this is useful, it does not allow you full access to all operations, facilities etc, including being able to update software and see the wifi scanning icon. The wifi scanning option should automatically populate once it is fully installed. Try this simple step before resorting to more complex configurations which are covered in other related threads (ensuring wifi is on/Up, wifi device driver installs, there are many other/ more time consuming reasons why it may not be working).